# WHERE condition across multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table...

```
--------------------------------------
| user_id |  status   |  status_date |
--------------------------------------
|    1    |  Current  |  2012-08-01  |
|    1    |  Referral |  2012-03-14  |
|    2    |  Referral |  2012-04-23  |
|         |           |              |
--------------------------------------
```

How would I query to find a distinct user_id who has a referral date before 2012-06-30 AND either a current date of after 2012-06-30 or no current status record at all?

Database is MySQL.

Comment: Just to clarify: When you say 'referral date', you mean `status_date = whatever` AND `status = referral`?

Comment: 'No current status record at all' - how do you expect to find the user id in that case?

Comment: Yes the status of 'Current' refers to the date '2012-08-01'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT T.User_ID
FROM    T
        LEFT JOIN T T2
            ON t.User_ID = T2.User_ID
            AND t2.Status = 'Current'
WHERE   T.Status_Date < '20120630'
AND     T.Status = 'Referral'
AND     (t2.Status_Date > '20120630' OR t2.Status_date IS NULL)
```

Or, using `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` and `COUNT(CASE ...)`

```
SELECT  t.User_ID
FROM    T
GROUP BY t.user_ID
HAVING  COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Status = 'Referral' AND t.Status_Date < '20120630' THEN 1 END) > 0
AND (   COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Status = 'Current' AND t.Status_Date > '20120630' THEN 1 END) > 0
    OR  COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Status = 'Current' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
    )
```

It will depend on your indexes and amount of data as to which performs better, I'd imagine in most cases it will be the former

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM YourTable T
WHERE status = 'Referral' 
AND status_date < '2012-06-30'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT user_id FROM YourTable 
                WHERE user_id = T.user_id AND status = 'Current' 
                AND status_date < '2012-06-30')
```

Comment: inside the not exists use `status_date <= '2012-06-30'`

Comment: @deathApril That particular border case was somewhat ambiguous to me, so I just chose one. Op can easily adapt it to his needs

Comment: I don't think this satisfies the criteria properly, having no current record or a current record after `2012-06-30` is not synonymous with does not have a current record before `2012-06-30` as you query implies. If User_ID 1 had another record with the status as current with the date before `2012-06-30` it would be excluded from the results despite satisfying the criterion of having a current record after this date. [Example Fiddle To Demonstrate](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e12f9/4)

Comment: @GarethD I don't think this will be a problem because if another user_id 1 has a current date before 2012-06-30 I would want that record excluded anyway (I am trying to get numbers on a waiting list between the start of April and end of June)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid doing innner selects with MySQL.  All versions up to and including 5.5 cannot optimize properly with them.  Use JOINs:

```
SELECT distinct t1.user_id 
  FROM tablename t1 
  LEFT JOIN tablename t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.status != t2.status
  WHERE t1.status = 'Referral' 
        AND t1.status_date '2012-06-30' 
        AND ( (t2.status IS NULL) OR 
              (t2.status = 'Current' AND t2.status_date > '2012-06-30'));
```

Comment: missing quotes on your dates. it'll be parsed as a subtraction and become `1976`. Plus... what's with the chained `>` in the last clause?

Comment: This does not work as set out in the question. With the example data User_Id 2 will be excluded from the results because in your join it is joining to the same row, therefore status is not null (it is referral), and status is not `current`, so the row is excluded. [Demonstration on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e12f9/7);

Comment: @GarethD  Good catch, forgot a `AND t1.status != t2.status` in my join condition!